# Why are input data transferrd to Variable type?

Tags: pytorch, yolo

I'm reading code that implementing YOLOv3 with Pytorch, and coming with a line like this:

```py
    for batch_i, (_, imgs, targets) in enumerate(dataloader):
            batches_done = len(dataloader) * epoch + batch_i
            imgs = Variable(imgs.to(device))  # ??
            targets = Variable(targets.to(device), requires_grad=False)
```

imgs is the input data, and I can't understand why there exits the transform: `Variable(imgs.to(device)))`
Does this mean that the input data should be trained(since the default option is that requires_grad=true) or is there another reason?

Comment: Yeah, this code doesn't make sense

Comment: Thanks you guys! But I now get the point of this code. This code is trying to convert the input data type to "cuda"  type for GPU. Since the weights I use is torch.cuda.FloatTensor, and the input data type should stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

As Natthaphon pointed out in his comment I don't really see the calls to Variable make any sense in the scenario.

Technically the Variable automatically becomes part of the computational graph. So maybe it's written by someone coming over from tensorflow or with visualization of the complete computational graph in mind.

Answer (score 0):

if you read doc [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html#variable-deprecated/)

the Variable API has been deprecated.
Hence, we should not bother using Variable to wrap a tensor anymore.
you can proceed with the variable wrapper in latest torch version.